# CSS anchor hover image transition

Tags: html, css, hover, anchor, transition

I'm having issues getting my image to transition when hovered over, I believe the issue is with the css `.play_button a:hover`
when changed to `#play_button a:hover` it will transition however `-webkit-transition` no longer works.

Here's my current code: http://jsbin.com/vesuravabu/edit?html,css,output

Thanks for your help.

edit: added the transition to the example that I was trying to use.

This question is now answered, thank you everyone who replied.
I changed it from ".play_button a:hover" to "#play_button a:hover"
I also found the issue with my transition, accidentally used a semi-colon after -webkit-transition

Comment: Looks like you have a class (.) instead of id (#) on the css definition for `:hover`. You mentioned a transition but no transitions are defined.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the id/class situation, and sorry I forgot to apply the transition in my example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

You don't have any class which is called `play_button`(`.play_button`). You can change `.play_button` to `#play_button` to solve your problem.

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yetimiboro/edit?html,css,output)

```css
#play_button a {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/119x69) repeat-y;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding: 0 36px;
  width: 119px;
  height: 69px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#play_button a:hover {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x150);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="sidebar_item">

    <div id="play_button">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to be using `#play_button a:hover` as opposed to `.play_button a:hover`, because `play_button` is an id, not a class name.

I don't see any `-webkit-transition` statements in your example, how are you trying to use this?  It's not possible to transition, using CSS transitions, from one image to another in this manner.  However, you could accomplish this a slightly different way:  have a second DOM element overlaid on top of the first, set to `opacity: 0` with the hover image already applied to this top element.  Then, `transition` the opacity to `1` when hovering.  This may give the effect you're looking for.

*EDIT:*  Now that you've added a transition, we can fix that too.  Note that in your example, "webkit" is misspelled, but the main problem is that you didn't specify the new width and height to transition to.  Give this a try:

```
#play_button a
{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/119x69) repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 0 36px;
    width: 119px;
    height: 69px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;  /* Don't need webkit prefix here for modern browsers */
    box-sizing: border-box;  /* Tell browser: Don't include padding in size calculations */
}

#play_button a:hover
{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200x150);  /* This will snap, not transition */
    width: 200px; /* New width & height, will be used for transition */
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution it sounds promising, however I'm a little confused by it, could you please explain it by code instead of words or just give an example? I'm pretty new to using html and css.